# Problem with Easy Gallery in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I installed Easy Gallery on a Joomla 1.5 site and initially it worked beautifully.  Then after I had installed / uninstalled a slideshow plugin, only one half of a selected image would appear in the lightbox (can't guarantee that this is the reason, but it was the only thing that I have changed).  I've searched high and low for an answer.  I really liked this plugin - did everything I wanted - and then something went awry.  It may have something to do with slimbox, from what I've read.   Also, strangely, the problem only occurred in Chrome and FireFox - in IE the images came up without any problem.

The site is getting a lot of visits at the moment and I've had to install another gallery while trying to sort this one out.

Comment: You need to post a link to a page that is having the problem. There is no way to diagnose the problem with the information you have given. If nothing else, Firebug should come up with some errors to help figure out the issue.